# How to access the client certificate chain from python web service?

Tags: python, web-services, certificate, x509

I would like to access the client X.509 certificate chain from within a web service which is implemented in some simple, RESTful python web service framework. Can this be done easily, and how?

I'm talking about a client connecting to the web server on https and presenting a client certificate. The web server can authenticate this for me -- that's preferred. But later, when the web service code is running, I want to look at the accepted certificate, including the chain to the trusted root.

I know how to do that with OpenSSL in C, if I am managing the TLS connection myself in some non-web server application. What I want is to do the same thing from within the python-based web service invoked by a web server.

I may be looking at the certificate chain to find white-listed certificates for example. I'm not interested in just the DN -- I want the entire certificate including the public key.

Comment: I don't think the question can be answered in general. You would have to restrict the question to a specific Python web service framework to make this answerable.